# R Shiny turn modules with UI and Server component on and off in app

Tags: r, module, shiny

I'm wondering if its possible to let my users turn certain modules on and off within my app.

My modules functionally each contain one analysis and are technically build with a server- and UI-function.

I would like the user to select witch modules/analyses he or she would like to view.

I've tried (for testing) to put them in an if else statement that listens to a pickerinput.

Most strip down example of such an app:

```
  ui <- dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(title = NULL),
      dashboardSidebar(
          width = '100%',
          disable  = TRUE
      ),
      dashboardBody(
          fluidRow(
              box(
                  title = "Modular modules", width = NULL, background = "blue",
                  h5(
                      paste('Version: ', packageVersion("modular modules"))
                  )
              )
          )
          fluidRow(
              pickerInput(inputId = 'select_modules',
                          label = 'Moules',
                          choices = c('Mod1', 'Mod2'),
                          selected = NULL,
                          multiple = FALSE)
          ),
          uiOutput('modulesUI'))
          )

          server <- function(input, output, session) {          

                observeEvent(input$select_modules,{
                    output$modulesUI <- renderUI(
                        if(input$select_modules == 'mod1'){
                        fluidRow(
                            mod1_UI(id = 'mod1')
                        )
                    } else if(input$select_modules == 'mod2'){
                        fluidRow(
                            mod2_UI(id = "mod2")
                        )
                    }
                    )
                })

            observeEvent(input$select_modules,{
                if(input$select_modules == 'mod1'){
                    callModule(mod1,
                               id = 'mod1',
                               ...
                                   )
                } else if(input$select_modules == 'mod2'){
                    callModule(mod2,
                               id = "mod2",
                              ...
                    )
                }
            })
```

My solutions do not work. Can this be done? And if it can, how?

Comment: Since you don't have a complete example here I am having a hard time understanding how this was supposed to work. To change ui elements, you need to use something like `uiOutput` or `htmlOutput`. That `observeEvent` will do nothing to change the ui element. As it stands even if you replaced that `observeEvent` with a uiOutput, it wouldn't work because you need to return the ui elements to be shown instead of ending the functions with `print`s. After that it becomes a question of whether or not call module will from inside an `observe` function.

Comment: I've edditted by post with a more complete example. I do use uiOutput to display the in the server generated UI. The print-statements where just there to show me that the observe event was working properly:)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you mean by "turning off" a module, but something like this works like a charm:

**Code**

```
## Define 2 modules
module1_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    h3("Distribution"),
    sliderInput(ns("sld"), "n", 10, 100, 10),
    plotOutput(ns("pl"))
  )}

module1 <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$pl <- renderPlot(hist(rnorm(input$sld)))
}

module2_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    h3("Boxplot"),
    numericInput(ns("nui"), "n:"),
    plotOutput(ns("pl"))
  )}

module2 <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$pl <- renderPlot(boxplot(rnorm(input$nui)))
}


## in the main ui have a select input and a ui placeholder 
## to select which module to show and to render it
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("mod", "Module:", c("Module 1", "Module 2")),
  uiOutput("mod_placeholder")
)

## in the server call the handlers either statically or dynamically
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  active_handler <- reactiveVal()

  observe({
    req(input$mod)
    if (input$mod == "Module 1") {
      active_handler(callModule(module1, "m1"))
    } else {
      active_handler(callModule(module2, "m2"))
    }
  })


  ## a static approach like this would also work
  ## handler <- list(mod1 = callModule(module1, "m1"),
  ##                 mod2 = callModule(module2, "m2")) 

  output$mod_placholder <- renderUI({
    if (input$mod == "Module 1") {
      module1_ui("m1")
    } else {
      module2_ui("m2")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Remarks**

This toy example is pretty hard coded, so in your use case I would put all the modules (ui and server) in a list and loop over this list. Then adding a new module is rather easy, ebcasue you have just to add server and ui function to this list and the rest updates automatcially.